# Do possessed weapon upgrades scale with level?

Tags: darksiders-2

Possessed weapons can be upgraded by sacrificing items to them. If I wait til a higher level to upgrade my weapon, will the upgrade be more powerful than if I upgraded it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it, no. Each item in Darksiders has a level, and the bonus of a Possessed weapon is that feeding it items will increase its level.

So it's not an issue of upgrading a weapon at level 3 vs. level 13, it's finding a possessed weapon of level 2 (and upgrading it to level 7) vs. finding a possessed weapon of level 5 (and upgrading it to level 10).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Just thought of that, after I finished upgrading my level 13 possessed weapon all the way. The first time I found a possessed weapon was while I was going through an old area, so it was a third my level -.-

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to find a level 30 possessed weapon for the best stats.

a good guide on possessed weapons

Comment: It looks like this contains information on later parts of the game, so I'm going to avoid it like the plague until I'm near the end.